# Storing html in database for simple WYSIWYG CMS

Tags: sql, node.js, database

I am trying to make a very simple CMS for a Node/Express backend.
I haven't found any free Headless CMS, so I am going to have a page with a WYSIWYG. (Specifically, I'm using CK Editor 5, which has a very simple API.)
A page will just have an input for the heading and a CKEditor textarea for the body-content. 
Once I have the data transmitted to the server, I obviously need to store it. I am going to use either mysql or sqlite as my database.
I'm aware that I need to avoid SQL injection. 
What is the best practice about storing user-uploaded content? Should I just store the HTML as a blob in the database?
I am using [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) module.
I have the following code:

```
router.post('/cms', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  db.prepare(`INSERT INTO blogposts (title, body) VALUES (${req.body.main_title}, ${req.body.content})`).run(); 
  res.send('post added to database!');
})
```

It is erroring with the message 'near "<": syntax error'

Also, if anyone knows of any Markdown wysiwyg editor that is as easy for non-technical people to use as CKEditor, please let me know!

Comment: It looks like you want to use a SQL prepare statement, you don't insert any values in a prepared statement like that, usually you prepare it with placeholder values like `?` and then fill it later. Maybe look at some DB prepared statement examples with Node JS, I'm sure there are plenty out there.

Comment: Most resources about Node only talk about how to do things with Mongo/noSQL

Comment: Actually in your case it makes sense to use a noSQL DB, a relational DB is not made for storing large data in a single field. Just saying. :)

Comment: Thank for the advice Xander. I'm only using sql because I have a (small) amount of knowledge about it already. I'll check out NoSQL. However, the vast majority of CMS do use SQL (Wordpress etc). Are they all making the wrong decision?